# How can we Stack XGBOOST model with dense neural networks

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, xgboost

i am  a newbie in ML , i was trying to solve a multi-class classification problem . I have used XGBOOST to reduce the log loss, I also tried a Dense neural network to reduce the log loss , it also seem to work well. Now is there a way i can stack these two models so that i can further reduce the log loss.

Comment: Have you thought about simply combining the outputs of the models run independently?

Comment: No, i have  not tried that , i am getting the probability values for the models ,so according to you i should take avg of their probabilty value outputs?

Comment: Average of the normalized outputs could work, yes. It would be like a mini ensemble, right?

Comment: glad to be of help!

Answer (score 0):

You can do it with Apple [coremltools](https://apple.github.io/coremltools/index.html).

1. Take your XGBoost model and convert to MLModel using the [converter](https://apple.github.io/coremltools/generated/coremltools.converters.xgboost.convert.html).
2. Create a [pipeline model](https://apple.github.io/coremltools/generated/coremltools.models.pipeline.html) combining that model with any neural networks.

I'm sure there are other tools with pipeline. But you will need to convert XGBoost to some other format.